# it always says invalid syntax in my code, how can i solve this?

Tags: python

```
def readVenueList(textFile):
    venuelist = []
    venue = open ("venue.txt","r")

    for x in venue :
        x = x.split(",")
        Name = "Name":(x[0])
        Max = "Max": int(x[1])
        Cost = "Cost": int(x[2])
        venuedict = {Name,Max,Cost}
        venuelist.append(venuedict)

    venue.close()
    return venuelist
```

Comment: provide sample content of venue.txt adnd also what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: May be you tried to do this: `venuedict = {"Name":x[0],"Max": int(x[1]),"Cost": int(x[2])}`

Answer (score 3):

When you write `Name = "Name" : (x[0])` it doesn't define a dictionary, it gives you a syntax error. You can use

`venuedict = {"Name" : x[0], "Max" : int(x[1]), "Cost" : int(x[2])}`

instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear, however try using this:

```
def readVenueList(textFile):
    venuelist = []
    venue = open ("venue.txt","r")

    for x in venue :
        x = x.split(",")
        Name = "Name : %s" % (x[0])
        Max = "Max : %s" % int(x[1])
        Cost = "Cost : %s" % int(x[2])
        venuedict = {Name,Max,Cost}
        venuelist.append(venuedict)

    venue.close()
    return venuelist
```

What are you trying to do with this anyway:

```
Name = 'name': (x[0])
```